# How to realise a multi-tier architecture with subsets of clients in different size?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I have read the four tutorials given by the tensorflow-federated. However, it just simply mentioned that the tff_core can be used for implementing the multi-tier network without any detailed instructions. In my implementation, I'd like to design a three-tier network with the subsets of clients in different sizes. My questions are:

1. Currently, I just use python code to represent the learning in a subset level. Is there any API I can use to replace my python code?
2. I am a bit confused about declaring the number of clients, the second part of the federated core tutorial just use `federated_map(local_train, [model, learning_rate, data])` to realize that. Does it mean the number of clients, in this case, is the number of elements in the data array?
3. In addition to question 2, the tutorial uses `tff.federated_broadcast` for passing the model and learning rate to all clients. If I have a three-tier architecture, does the `tff.federated_broadcast` still make sense?
4. Lastly, for the second-layer server, should I treat it as `SERVER` or `CLIENTS`?

Answer (score 0):

TFF's design does support additional levels of placement, but currently there are only two canned placements: `CLIENTS` and `SERVER`. Furthermore, some of the intrinsics only support particular placement changes (e.g. `tff.federated_broadcast` moves data from `SERVER` to `CLIENTS`, but cannot broadcast data from `CLIENTS` to `CLIENTS`). Support for custom placements has not been implemented yet.

Depending on how the multi-tier network is configured it possibly is still expressible in TFF now; albeit a bit unclearly due to the lack of additional placement labels.

1. Currently this must be done at the Python level, there is no support yet.
2. Correct, the number of clients is the number of elements in the array. TFF parameterizes clients by the data they hold. To realize two sets of clients, the code could have two different lists of arguments (potentially of different sizes).
3. Depends on what is trying to be achieved. The answer could change based on whether the goal is to model a fleet of devices with different values, or all holding the same value.
4. More information is likely needed, the answer would depend on how the second layer is going to be used.

Comment: Hi Zachary, thank you for your answer, that helps me a lot. I have another question concerning the performance. Does the tff doesn't support  GPU well as it mainly focuses on the simulation rather than the performance?

Comment: TFF delegates to TF; code wrapped in a `@tff.tf_computation` will be run using TensorFlow. Even in simulation the GPU can be used to train models, and speedups may be seen during this training.